LiveData not updating UI even with clone
I have use clone to create new object and update like that:
fun sync(item: LibraryItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val debugValue = item.userMediaProgress.toUpload
        val updated = apiHandler.updateProgress(item.userMediaProgress)
        if (updated) {
            val newItem = item.copy()
            newItem.userMediaProgress.toUpload = !debugValue
            _item.postValue(newItem)
        }
    }
}

But I dont get changes in UI. When I create new complete object it works. Why?

Can you provide a [mre] so we can test that out for ourselves?

I have found that it is because of shallow copy and needed to copy userMediaPorgress to live data detect changes:
fun sync(item: LibraryItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val debugValue = item.userMediaProgress.toUpload
        val updated = true
        if (updated) {
            val newUserMediaProgress = item.userMediaProgress.copy(toUpload = !debugValue)
            val newItem = item.copy(userMediaProgress = newUserMediaProgress)
            _item.postValue(newItem)
        }
    }
}

